# Is SVM with the mnist dataset 100% accurate?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, mnist

So I wrote a program using `sklearn`'s `svm.SVC` module to learn the mnist dataset, for some reason whenever i calculate the accuracy its 100%. This seems too good to be true, is this expected?

```py
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

digits = datasets.load_digits()

clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100)
print(len(digits.data))
train_with_first = 50

x, y = digits.data[:-train_with_first], digits.target[:-train_with_first]
clf.fit(x,y)

print(digits.data[4])

num_corr = 0
num_total = 0

for pred in range(train_with_first-1):    
    prediction = clf.predict(digits.data[pred].reshape(1,-1))
    target = digits.target[pred]
    print(int(target))
    print(int(prediction))

    if int(target) == int(prediction):
        num_corr += 1 
    num_total += 1

print("Accuracy was: ", (float(num_corr)/num_total)*100)
```

I expect the accuracy to be less than 100%

Comment: It seems you didn;t split it into training and testing set, it may be over-fitting with training set, try to predict with those data which is not in your training data.

Comment: @JimChen I did split the training data on line 10

Comment: The way you use is to training your model with data 0 to data n-50, and you do prediction with your data from data 0 to data 50, so the prediction data you use is all in your training data, try to use `train_test_split` in sklearn to split training and testing set.

Comment: @JimChen that worked, you can go ahead and put it as an answer so that I can mark it correct and give you the reputation

Comment: MNIST has predefined training and testing splits, you aren't using them.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro how can i access them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be over-fitting because the prediction data you use is all in your training data, try to use `train_test_split` in sklearn to split training and testing set.

Or you can change line 18 from

`for pred in range(train_with_first-1):`

to

`for pred in range(train_with_first,len(digits.data)):`

but use `train_test_split` is recommended.